# Are there any native tools for SVG conversion on OS X?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, graphics, file-conversion

How can I convert SVG image to something raster? Are there any native [command-line] tools on OS X that can do that? I am able to open them in Safari or Firefox, but doing "Save as..." only proposes original (.svg) or web-archive formats and no rasterized image format.

Comment: This link produced the best results for me: http://www.fileformat.info/convert/image/svg2pdf.htm

Comment: There are lots of answers here: https://superuser.com/questions/134679/command-line-application-for-converting-svg-to-png-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Also answers about converting from SVG here. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66354/is-there-a-free-command-line-program-for-converting-pdf-files-to-svg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with **Inkscape**:

```
/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/script --without-gui --export-png=raster-image.png  source-image.svg
```

To change output resolution you can set the DPI value:

```
/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/script --without-gui --export-png=raster-image.png --export-dpi=200  source-image.svg
```

[Here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inkscape) are more command line options.

Comment: inkscape 0.91 current version doesn't seem to display svg images properly, and therefore the conversion to a png is 'correct' as far as this broken inkscape is concerned, but doesn't result in the correct images. YMMV but I would be careful before relying too heavily on inkscape for this purpose. Note that I have used inkscape in exactly this way myself until I've come across an SVG that it breaks on.

Answer (score 13):

Try [Gapplin](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gapplin/id768053424?mt=12). It works for me and creates PNG and JPG files from SVG. Simple and effective.

If you have a lot of SVG files to convert, ImageMagick is probably your best bet (available directly from [imagemagick.org](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx) or via Homebrew).

Comment: Best I can find after tried imagemagic and qlmanage.

Comment: Gapplin is easy to use, and it helped me. Thanks for sharing the link.

Comment: @wanghq I had lousy results with ImageMagick on Mojave. I suspect I didn't set all the flags, etc., but [CairoSVG](https://cairosvg.org) is dirt simple to use. I was able to easily convert SVGs to PDFs that Xcode didn't puke on.

Comment: Installation of ImageMagick (via Homebrew) took more than 1 hour.

Comment: I have an SVG that doesn't render properly when using the online conversion sites like cloudconvert. Gapplin solved the issue.

Answer (score 8):

https://cloudconvert.org/svg-to-png - was fastest way for me.
it's not my site.

Comment: It's not native though...

Comment: Absolutely native. Works in any browser and solves the problem. Sure this answer will be useful for somebody.

Comment: Different definitions of 'native' here. OP's 'native' refers to a Mac binary application.

Answer (score 2):

One (wonky) option would be to render it in Safari and take a screenshot of the result, although that's obviously not a good solution.

Sadly there's little SVG support in OS X so far apart from Safari, Preview.app (the obvious choice for image format conversion) can't render it and I'm not aware of any bundled command line tools that can either.

As for third party command line tools, [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) makes [Cairo's](https://www.cairographics.org/) svg2png as well as the [ImageMagick bundle](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) easily available.